# Comprehending ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.4

I have reviewed this well-asked and answered PG permission question, and I use it as a starting point for my question:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema

How can I observe the differences between:

```
alter default privileges for role schma_admin
    grant select, insert, delete, truncate on tables to schma_mgr;
```

... and ...

```
alter default privileges for role schma_mgr -- "admin" and "mgr" are swapped
    grant select, insert, delete, truncate on tables to schma_admin;
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first statement, all tables newly created by `schema_admin` will automatically have the specified privileges granted to `schema_mgr`.

So every table created by `schema_admin` will have `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` privileges granted to `schema_mgr` (in addition to having all privileges granted to the owner).

In the second statement, the roles are reversed, so tables created by `schema_mgr` will have privileges granted to `schema_admin`.

Note that this does not affect tables created *before* the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't run the 1st command with "are swapped."  I edited my question to move it to the 2nd command.  I will edit it now.  What do you mean, "the roles are reversed?"

Comment: @Laurenze Albe I've thought about what you said. Are you saying that the 1st statement confers all privileges of schma_admin plus S/I/D/T on to schma_mgr?  What happens to the privileges of schma_mgr if you change the privileges of schma_admin?

Comment: I have edited the answer in an attempt to make the situation clearer.